# Make timetracking a synonym of the time-tracking tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

I think tags [time-tracking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-tracking) and [timetracking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/timetracking) should be synonyms because their difference is only hyphen

Answer (score 2):

The train pulled into the station on a humid afternoon. Out jumped the single tag and fell into a pot mixed with the group. Together, at last. The sibling come home.

[timetracking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/timetracking) is now a synonym of [time-tracking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-tracking) and it keeps on slipping, slipping, slipping...

Comment: I see what you did there...